# c3p0 ComboPooledDataSource report largest pool size?

Tags: java, reporting, c3p0

I'm implementing some runtime reporting for my web app, which is using c3p0's `ComboPooledDataSource`.  I'm wondering if there's a way to programmatically get the largest number of connections that have ever been in the pool so far. Something to the same effect as [ThreadPoolExecutor.getLargestPoolSize()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html#getLargestPoolSize%28%29).

I can see a number of reporting methods on `ComboPooledDataSource`, but haven't been able to find something like this. It hasn't helped that there doesn't appear to be any (meaningful) c3p0 javadocs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I scoured the API and couldn't find anything. Here's my simple workaround:

```
static final ComboPooledDataSource dataSource = new ComboPooledDataSource();

static volatile int largestPoolSize = 0;

public static Connection getConnection() throws SQLException {
    Connection connection = dataSource.getConnection();
    updateLargestPoolSize();
    return connection;
}

private static void updateLargestPoolSize() throws SQLException {
    int numConnections = dataSource.getNumConnections();
    if (numConnections > largestPoolSize) {
        largestPoolSize = numConnections;
    }
}
```

If anyone can suggest something more sophisticated, please post.